# Only partial data was loaded from EXCEL source to OLEDB destination

Tags: ssis

I was loading data from EXCEL source to OLEDB destination and put a Data Conversion in between.

My source include column like this

ROOM_NO

B2

B2

101

102

103

101

I didn't get the right result, so I checked my data viewer. It's like this

ROOM_NO

NULL

NULL

101

102

103

101

I was told that the reason is I only have two row in nvarchar type, but 4 rows in float, so EXCEL source consider it as float.
So I went to the advance editor and found the Input and Output Property tab and changed the external columns and Output columns to nvarchar 255. I still got NULLs. Then I changed ValidateExternalMetadata to false under Component Property tab. Again, NULLs - -! Could anyone help me out here?

Thank you.

Eddie

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone. Problem solved. Many thanks to Lydia, who helped me out. Just want to share the answer to anyone who might got into the same trouble like I did.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e1c43fdc-c3a1-4a6c-8026-4d18440acceb/only-partial-data-was-loaded-from-excel-source-to-oledb-destination?forum=sqlintegrationservices&prof=required